# add a library folder recursively in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to link all libraries (.so files) in a path to a built target.
If I have only one library to link with:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib/
LDLIBS=-lconfig
OBJS=test.o
test: ${OBJS} 
${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LDLIBS}
```

If I have many then I have to do something like this

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib/
LDLIBS=-lconfig -lmylib1 -lmylib2 -lmylib3 ...
OBJS=test.o
test: ${OBJS} 
${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LDLIBS}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this by not specifying the name of all the .so files?

Comment: That depends.  What are the filenames of your .so files?  Are the all `libfoo.so`, or do they have version extensions like `libfoo.so.1` etc.?  In general I think this is a bad idea and will only lead to tears.  You should list the libraries you want to link explicitly.  It's not so bad: there can't be THAT many of them and they hardly ever change.

Comment: @MadScientist They have version extensions. I will do the explicit way at this moment if there are no other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.  As in my comment above, I really discourage people from simply linking a passel of libraries in some random order.  But if you really want to do it:

```
LIBDIR = /usr/local/lib
LDFLAGS = -L$(LIBDIR)
LDLIBS := $(patsubst lib%,-l%,$(foreach L,$(wildcard $(LIBDIR)/*.so*),$(firstword $(subst ., ,$L))))
```

Note 1: This will not work if your library root name contains `.`; for example it will fail if you have `libfoo.bar.so.1` or similar.

Note 2: I wrote this in this comment and it's not tested :)